# Android studio is not showing the home page after loading

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed the Android studio version 2.2.3 in Windows 8.1. When I click on the Android Studio icon it will load completely and then it doesn't show the home page of it. It doesn't throw any errors. After a long time, it is in the same state.

I have JDK on my laptop already and I have tried all your solutions posted in the website. The Android icon appears and loads until the end and doesn't show the home page.

Comment: Please note, these sort of questions is not this site is meant for, Its very general question your asking about IDE, please refer to IDE documentations for details like this.

Comment: You should reach the location where AS stores logs and see if there's something relevant to post here